# Mantener un Tab o Pestañas en la misma posición al dar clic en un botón -Laravel

Tags: javascript, html, laravel, bootstrap, datatables

Cordial saludo tengo un inconveniente y es por eso que recurro a su ayuda y la agradezco de antemano, actualmente tengo un proyecto que posee Taps y dentro de cada tap posee su respectiva tabla como se puede apreciar en la imagen:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Para este proyecto uso los tabs de bostrap y para las tablas uso DataTables.

```
<nav>
  <div class="nav nav-tabs" id="nav-tab" role="tablist">
   <a class="nav-link active" id="nav-home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-home" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-home" aria-selected="true"><i class="fas fa-envelope"></i> EMISOR</a>
   <a class="nav-link" id="nav-profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-profile" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-profile" aria-selected="false"><i class="fas fa-inbox"></i> RESPONSABLE</a>
   <a class="nav-link" id="nav-admin-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-admin" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-admin" aria-selected="false"><i class="fas fa-toolbox"></i> ADMIN</a>                 
 </div>
</nav>
```

Mi problema o duda parte en la columna **"APROBACIÓN"** es un botón que al dar clic cambia el estado a aprobado o viceversa

```
@if ($tarea->estado_general == "0")
<a href="{{ url('/administrador/tareas/'.$tarea->id.'/estado')}}" class="btn btn-warning ">
       &#9866;
   </a>
 @else
  <a href="{{ url('/administrador/tareas/'.$tarea->id.'/estado')}}" class="btn btn-success ">
     &#10003;
  </a>
 @endif
```

Y este es mi controlador

```
public function geTareastestado($id){
    $tareas = Tareas::findOrFail($id);
    if($tareas->estado_general == "0"):
       $tareas->estado_general = "1";
       $msg = "Aprobado";
    else:
       $tareas->estado_general = "0";
       $msg = "Pendiente";
    endif;
    if($tareas->save()):     
       return back()->with('message',$msg)->with('typealert','warning');
    endif;
 }
```

quisiera que al dar clic al botón de aprobación no regrese a el tap principal sin no que se quede en el que estaba

> Ejemplo: si estoy en el tap de administrador y le doy botón de aprobación se envía pero se recarga la pagina y me lleva al tap de emisor quisiera que al recargar se quede en el tap de administrador

al ver los taps de bostrap veo que posee una clase **active** quiza pueda hacer una función con javascript que al dar clic a APROBACION no cambie de posición, si fuera así me podrían guiar a como hacerlo o otra manera recomendada
Agradezco su tiempo y ayuda.